# Using JavaScript from Selenium RC by Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I have the following function in `user-extensions.js`

```
file:Selenium.prototype.doTypeRepeated = function(locator, text) {
    // All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
    var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

    // Create the text to type
    var valueToType = text + text;

    // Replace the element text with the new text
    this.page().replaceText(element, valueToType);
};
```

I am using Selenium RC with Java. I have the Java class file "Services_ProcMethodREOI.java". I used the following line in Java file to call the javascript function `typeRepeated()`:

```
selenium.getEval("typeRepeated(\"txtAppCode\", \"service5\")");
//txtAppCode is a textfield and service5 is the inputted text on that textfield
```

When I ran the Java file using eclipse, I found the following error:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Threw an
>   exception: Object expected

Pls suggest me how can I solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the doCommand method to fire off your new command that you have created. THere is good documentation at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-rc